# mysql compare takes too much time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Using 3 tables here listed below:

```
 CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `del` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `kid` (`kid`),
  KEY `email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=MyISA
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `blacklist_global` (
  `bgid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `kid` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stmp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bgid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `kid` (`kid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `verteiler_user` (
  `vuid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `del` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`vuid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

every entry in table `user` is also in table `verteiler_user`. now i want to `delete` every entry from user `where  user.uid = verteiler_user.uid and verteiler_user.vid=XX and user.uid = XXX`

so atm im doing it from php fetch all entrys from table `user`, all from `blacklist_global`.
the problem is, in the blacklist i could enter *@heloooo.de so i want to delete every email from the domain helooo.de but its very very slow.

is it possible to do it only in `mysql`? without `php` ? or any tip, of doing this faster ?

Answer (score 0):

This might get what you need. Test it first before using it on production data.

`DELETE FROM user WHERE uid = ? AND uid in (SELECT uid from verteiler_user WHERE vid = ?)`

Edited based on comment:

`DELETE FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM blacklist_global WHERE email LIKE '%@somedomain.com')`

Comment: the problem is that i had to check the email adress, i want to delete all from user if the user.email is listet in blacklist.email but in blacklist.email could be a wildcard like *@bla.de so i want to delete from user where email like blaa..

Comment: @Roby I added an example based on your comment.

Comment: thx for the fast replay, but i had to check if the character bevor the @ is a * then do it like email LIKE '%@somedomain.com and if not just check for the full email, did you understand what i mean ?

Comment: The wildcard character in MySQL is % not *. So if you want do write code to handle * you need to replace it before you do the query in mysql.

Comment: true but in my db is an entry like *@hui.de i cannot replace it atm.... so is it possible to to it with mysql ?